# Fixup initialisation for residual networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In their [Fixup Initialization: Residual Learning Without Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09321), authors suggest:

> Fixup initialization (or: How to train a deep residual network without normalization)
>   1. Initialize the classification layer and the last layer of each residual branch to **0**.
>   2. Initialize every other layer using a standard method (e.g., Kaiming He), and scale only the weight layers inside residual branches by ... .
>   3. Add a scalar multiplier (initialized at 1) in every branch and a scalar bias (initialized at 0) before each convolution, linear, and element-wise activation layer.

I used to think that [zero init](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#init) is a pitfall. What am I missing?

[image: a cutout from Figure 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zeros initialization is a pitfall, but as far a i see and someone can correct me if i am wrong.

Here they are only initializing the second conv filter with zeros, with multiple modifications like adding a bias before the conv and rescaling the first conv by the position of the layer.So all these together help it avoid the the vanilla zero initialization.